# Ansible template error while templating string : unexpected char '@' in email

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'm using Ansible to get a list of user emails from an API and I want to loop over them.

This is the json response I get from the API:

```
"users": [
{
    "email": "email1@email.com",
    "id": 1,
    "is_admin": true
},
{
    "email": "email2@email.com",
    "id": 2,
    "is_admin": false
},
]
```

**edit:**
the task after that which I need the email for:

```
- name: Send emails
      register: result
      uri:
        url: http://api
        method: GET
        body_format: json
        return_content: yes
        body:
          email: "{{ item.email }}"
          scope: SCOPE
      loop: "{{ users.json['users'] }}"

- name: Print result
  debug:
    var: result
```

the error I get:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected char '@' at 16. String: {{ email@email.com }}"}
```

If I use `email: item.email` the json request body will be  `"body": {"email": "item.email"}` instead of the email value

How Can I get the full email of each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `{{` and `}}` markers from your `var:` directive. The value of `var` is implicitly evaluated in a Jinja template context so you don't need those markers:

```
- name: Print returned json dictionary
  debug:
    var: item.email
  loop: "{{ users.json['users'] }}"
```

---

(**Updated based on edits to your question**)

The example you've shown doesn't generate the error you're asking about. Here's a complete reproducer with just the `uri` changed:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    users:
      json:
        users:
          - email: email1@email.com
            id: 1
            is_admin: true
          - email: email2@email.com
            id: 2
            is_admin: false

  tasks:
    - name: Send emails
      register: result
      uri:
        url: https://eny1tdcqj6ghp.x.pipedream.net
        method: GET
        body_format: json
        return_content: true
        body:
          email: "{{ item.email }}"
          scope: SCOPE
      loop: "{{ users.json['users'] }}"
```

This runs without errors (although note that I'm suspicious about the
use of a `GET` request with a JSON body; typically you would expect
that to be a `POST` request).

You can see the result of running this playbook [here](https://requestbin.com/r/eny1tdcqj6ghp/26sbBYa7Vs3i40bE88oCpqs0gOB), which shows that the values being sent in the request are exactly what we expect from the data.

Comment: I just tried this, but when I try to use the item.email in another API request it ends up looking like this: `  "body": {"email": "item.email" } ` instead of getting the actual email

Comment: My mistake @larsks, I didn't explain how I will use the item.email well. I edited the post to fix that